# Como fazer um índice de um array não ser requirido numa validação com Respect Validation Key?

Tags: php

Estou utilizando o `Respect\Validation` para validar alguns campos do meu formulário. Estou usando o método `Validator::key()` para poder validar cada valor presente num índice do `array` que é enviado desse formulário.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
Validator::key('nome', Validator::notOptional()->stringType())
      ->key('tipo', Validator::in(['f', 'j']))
      ->key('telefone', Validator::optional(
            Validator::regex('/^\(\d{2}\)\d{4}-\d{4}$/')
        ))
      ->key('celular', Validator::optional(
            Validator::regex('/^\(\d{2}\)\d{5}-\d{4}$/')
        ))
      ->key('email', Validator::email()->notOptional())
      ->key('cidade', Validator::notOptional()->stringType());
```

O valor `telefone` e `celular` utilizei `Validator::optional()` para que os campos não necessitassem existir, mas, se existissem, os mesmos devem ser validados.

Porém quando envio o formulário sem preencher `celular`, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Key celular must be present

Gostaria de saber: como eu posso fazer para validar uma chave de um array com Respect Validation, porém apenas se a mesma existir?

Referências:

https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/docs/Key.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo o q u entendi da [documentação](http://respect.github.io/Validation/docs/key.html):

O método `key` tem 3 parâmetros, onde o terceiro é "obrigatorio".

Imagino que seria assim:

```
->key('celular', Validator::regex('/^\(\d{2}\)\d{5}-\d{4}$/'), false)
```

Na documentação tem essa explicação:

```
v::key(string $name, v $validator, boolean $mandatory = true)
```

Comment: É, isso funcionou. Esse terceiro parâmetro faz o valor ser validado apenas se não existir. Muito obrigado. +1

Comment: Marca como correta =]

Comment: kkkk, eu costumo demorar um bom tempo pra marcar mesmo. É um procedimento que me ensinaram aqui no site. Mas pode ficar tranquilo, provavelmente vou marcá-la sim.

Comment: Imagino que seja interessante esse "procedimento" quando se trata de algum algoritimo ou solução que pode ser diferente, nesse caso não tem segredo é a assinatura do médoto. Mas fique a vontade para marcar a hora que quiser.